# play audio in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop-application, flutter-dependencies

i made one demo in flutter its work fine in Android, iphone, linux desktop and mac desktop but in windows desktop it give me error

```
[ERROR:c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\flutter\lib\ui\ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method stop on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers)
```

can any one help me to resolve this error?

in this demo i used [audioplayers 0.14.2](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) to play local audio file in flutter.

here is my code:-

```
      void main() {
        debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
        runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleApp()));
      }

      class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        _ExampleAppState createState() => new _ExampleAppState();
      }

      class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
        AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
        AudioCache audioCache;

        @override
        void initState() {
          super.initState();
          initPlayer();
        }

        void initPlayer() {
          advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
          audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);
        }

        void playfirst() {
          audioCache.play('audio1.mp3');
        }

        void stop() {
          advancedPlayer.stop();
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: 1,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Audio file demo'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 48.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(child: Text("play"), onPressed: playfirst)),
                    ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 48.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(child: Text("stop"), onPressed: stop))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can any one help me to resolve this error?

The only way to resolve the error would be to write an implementation of that plugin for Windows; the reason it's telling you that the plugin is missing is that the plugin doesn't have Windows support (which you can tell because there's no `windows` folder in the plugin repository, or `windows:` entry in [the `pubspec.yaml`](https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/pubspec.yaml#L8)).

> its work fine in [...] linux desktop

That's surprising, given that the plugin you are using doesn't support Linux either.

It's unlikely that you're going to find a plugin that has Windows support at the moment given that [the official documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#create) currently says:

> **Note**: Windows and Linux plugin APIs and tooling are not yet stable, so any plugin written now will need frequent updates for breaking changes. Because of this, publishing Windows and/or Linux plugins to pub.dev at this stage is **strongly discouraged**.

Comment: thank you for ur answer do u have any idea to resolve this issue ?
or any other plugin to work around ?

Comment: My comment answered both of those questions.